# How to change the behaviour of a Label, in Python, based on a bound NumericProperty

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Question: How to change a Label's behavior, in python, triggered when the Event fires on a NumericProperty change?

I can do this in KivyLang, but I can't figure out how to do it in Python.

I have an external module which "sends" data to the Kivy app. Naturally, I wish widgets to be "bound" to the data - so they change automatically to reflect new data.  This is working, for example the following binds a label text to an incoming float value:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.event import EventDispatcher
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty

kv = """
Label:
    font_size: 50
    text: "Number: {}".format(app.data_store.exampleNumeric)
"""

class MyDataStore(EventDispatcher):
    exampleNumeric = NumericProperty(-1)
    exampleString: StringProperty("no data yet")

class HappyApp(App):
    data_store = ObjectProperty(MyDataStore(), rebind=True)

    #this func will be called from external modules, and kivy widgets should auto-refresh the new data 
    def UpdateDataStore(self, incomingdata):
       self.data_store.exampleNumeric = incomingdata

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

app=HappyApp()
#just using a Clock to simulate incoming data, to keep this question short
Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt : app.UpdateDataStore(42), 1)
app.run()
```

This works.  However I would like to develop more complex, reactive, behaviour. Simple example: make the Label turn Red colour, if  `exampleNumericProperty < 10`.

I can do this in kivy lang, for example like this:

```
<MyFloatLayout>:
    Label:
        font_size: 30
        text: "Number: {}".format(app.data_store.exampleNumeric)
        color: [1, 0, 0, 1] if app.data_store.exampleNumeric < 10 else [1,1,1,1]
```

But I don't know how to do that in Python...I don't know "where" to *trigger* behavioral changes of e.g a specific Label, so they automatically fire whenever a bound Property changes e.g "exampleNumericProperty.  Because I might need to make 5 or 10 UI changes, when `exampleNumericProperty` changes, and it seems a bit unweildly to do that in KV?

Specific Question:  The above KVLang will automatically detect if my numericpropery changes, and update the Label Colour accordingly.  How do I acheive exactly the same thing, in Python?

I might be thinking about this all wrong.  Corrections to bad thinking welcomed.  In my head, I'm looking for something like this.

```
kv = """
    Label:
        font_size: 50
        Monitor_exampleNumeric_for_changes:  
             self.do_several_things_to_update_this_label_if_exampleNumeric_changed()
    """

def somewhere.do_several_things_to_update_this_label_if_exampleNumeric_changed():
    n = app.data_store.exampleNumeric
    s = app.data_store.exampleString
    if n > 20: label.colour = red
    is s = "offline": label.font_size = 50
    is s = "online: label.text = ">>" + label.text
```

**Goal: seek to make a number of changes to the Label, depending on various other variables, to be triggered whenever one specific Property changes**

If this design.goal seems bad, very happy to be directed towards a better way of doing it.

Comment: Your posted code is not runnable. Try adding a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @ApuCoder sorry about that, thought I had tested it.  Have rewritten it so can be copy/pasted and run easily as a single file, tested.

Answer (score 0):

its simpler this way. consider this in kv i have a label this way:

```
Label:
    id: lb
    pos: ## whatever
    size: ## whatever
```

in main i have this:

```
Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_label, 1):

def update_label(self, *args):
    if float_data = ## whatever u need:
        self.ids.lb.color = [1, 1, 1, 1]  # white
    if float_data = ## whatever u need:
        self.ids.lb.color = [1, 0, 0, 1]  # red
```

u can start the clock whenver u need to and stop it like this `Clock.unschedule(self.update_label)`

Comment: Thankyou. But I think that gets messy with large code?  FYI I'm not using any Polling (no scheduled clock). It's purely event based. When I run `self.data_store.exampleNumericProperty = freshdata`, the Label will automatically update. because it has a binding to `exampleNumericProperty`.  However I'm trying to figure out how to "intercept" that event, in python, so I can do more advanced UI changes. (exactly like my example Kivy Lang code functions)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether or not I can follow you. But the following modified version of your example may meet your requirement.

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.event import EventDispatcher
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty

kv = """
Label:
    font_size: 50
    text: str(app.modified_value)
#    text: "Number: {}".format(app.data_store.exampleNumeric)
"""

class MyDataStore(EventDispatcher):
    exampleNumeric = NumericProperty(-1)
    exampleString: StringProperty("no data yet")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        # Bind a callback function to listen to any changes in its value.
        self.bind(exampleNumeric = self.modify_app_value)
        # Change its value (just a simulation).
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda *args : setattr(self, "exampleNumeric", 42), 1.0)


    def modify_app_value(self, instance, new_value):
        # Access the running app.
        app = App.get_running_app()
        # Now access and modify the target value, implement your logic here.
        app.modified_value = new_value
        # Or you can call the bound method from app.
#       app.UpdateDataStore(new_value)


class HappyApp(App):
    data_store = ObjectProperty(MyDataStore(), rebind=True)
    modified_value = NumericProperty(1) # This is the target value.

    #this func will be called from external modules, and kivy widgets should auto-refresh the new data.
    def UpdateDataStore(self, incomingdata):
       self.modified_value = incomingdata
       # Implement required logic here.
#       self.data_store.exampleNumeric = incomingdata

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

app=HappyApp()
#just using a Clock to simulate incoming data, to keep this question short
#Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt : app.UpdateDataStore(42), 1)
app.run()
```